# Multiple independent wordpress installs - 1 dedicated server - individual dedicated domain for each install. What is the best way to achieve this?

Tags: installation

Basically, what I need to achieve is multiple installs of wordpress on the same server but all each with their own independent domain/sql db/etc. I already have the domains, I just need to figure out the best way to hook this up. I have cpanel access if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Virtual Servers, that way you can redirect each domain to a specific wordpress installation (see Apache for that). To achieve the db side of it, you just need to hace a prefix for each wordpress installation (that's part of the setup).

In my case I'm not using cpanel, I have an AWS EC2 instance with LAMP and 4 wordpress installation working perfectly with apache's virtualserver.